# EXCEL VBA Combobox matching

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

**Explanation:**
[image]
*Image 1*

Based on the Image1, Level 1 is the Object and Level 2 is the type of the object.

[image] 
*Image 2*
In Image 2, as you can see I named them `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox2` for `Level 1` and `Level 2` respectively.

**What I want to achieve:**

1. When user select `ComboBox1`, it will display a set of `Level 1` items as shown in image from `A2:XFD2` without empty cells.
2. Then, based on the selection in `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2` will list out `Level 2` as shown in *Image 1* according to the value in `ComboBox1`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rnLevel1 As Range, rnLevel2 As Range, rnTemp As Range

Set rnLevel1 = Sheet1.Cells(2, Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count)

ComboBox2.Clear 'Clear all values first

For Each rnTemp In rnLevel1
    If rnTemp.Value <> "" And rnTemp.Value <> "Level 1" Then ' Add values NOT INCLUDING Level 1 to Combobox1
        ComboBox1.AddItem rnTemp.Value
    End If
Next


End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim rnLevel1 As Range, rnLevel2 As Range, rnTemp As Range

Set rnLevel1 = Sheet1.Cells(2, Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Find(ComboBox1.Value) 'Find the correct column
Set rnLevel2 = Sheet1.Range(rnLevel1.Offset(1, 0), Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, rnLevel1.Column).End(xlUp))

ComboBox2.Clear 'Clear all values first

For Each rnTemp In rnLevel2
    If rnTemp.Value <> "" Then  ' Add values to Combobox2
        ComboBox2.AddItem rnTemp.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```